# Website causing mobile Chrome browser to become non-responsive

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, mobile

I made this website for a client by editing a Bootstrap template and its working fine except that it keeps becoming unresponsive quite frequently.

Functions like zooming in and scrolling are almost always laggy.

What can cause mobile browser to crash(there is a popup in Chrome saying it has become unresponsive do I want to close app)?

Facebook works totally fine on this same device so I am sure it's something to do with my website.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code or a fiddle.

Comment: sorry i cant post the code right now but general tips on optmising website for mobile devices will help